# Table using css

Tags: css

I am using the following css to mimic a table:

```
.table {
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #f00; 
}

.table .th {
background-color: #f00;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #f00;
}

.table .td {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 23%;
 padding-left: 2%;
}
```

Is there a way to have line that will separate each row? 
Thanks, Evan

Comment: Why don't you use a real table?

Comment: **1.** Use a `<table>` for a table. **2.** What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Mimicking tables will only work on certain browsers (some of the latest vesions of Chrome, FF for sure) but have a lot of compatibility problems with versions of IE. However if you really want to do this you should add `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` to each of your classes.

Answer (score 3):

Please use tables rather than recreating tables. They have a purpose. If you are creating tubular data list, like a spreadsheet, then just use a table.

This is more of a pet peeve, but it's just a waste of code that quickly becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what the structure of your markup is but if you mimic a table row (.tr) and wrap each row of tds in it then you will have more styling control through the css.

If not, just applying a border-bottom to the td class will also work.

@seth is right too, there no no problem using tables to show data.

Comment: I was trying to use an alternative to tables because of a PDF making program I am using. Using php I generate a huge table using <table>. I am very happy with the structure of this table but the PDF-making program is not.